# Select rows based on dynamic criteria

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

currently I'm looking at this kind of dataset:

```
         date   income    account  flag  day  month  year
0  2018-04-13   470.57  1000 0002     8   13      4  2018  
1  2018-04-14   375.54  1000 0002     8   14      4  2018  
2  2018-05-15   375.54  1000 0002     8   15      5  2018  
3  2018-05-16   229.04  1000 0002     7   16      5  2018  
4  2018-06-17   216.62  1000 0002     7   17      6  2018  
5  2018-06-18   161.61  1000 0002     6   18      6  2018  
6  2018-04-19   131.87  0000 0001     6   19      4  2018  
7  2018-04-20   100.57  0000 0001     6   20      4  2018  
8  2018-08-21   100.57  0000 0001     6   21      8  2018  
9  2018-08-22    50.57  0000 0001     5   22      8  2018
```

I am working on a DecisionTree regression model comparing RandomForest, with ExtraTrees and adjusting some of its hyperparameters. What I am currently trying to do is split the dataset in order to keep the rows that have the max value of the column `month` for each unique value `account` (which could also be set to index if it makes anything easier) as test_set and the other ones as train_set. Basically this means the regression will be made with all the historical data available, except the data belonging to the last available month which will be used to validate the mse.

I know how to filter a dataframe based on a static criteria such as `df[df['month'] < 12]` but in this case I need to keep all the rows belonging the max month available for each different `account` value.

From the former dataset I should be able to get something like:`df_test =`

```
         date   income    account  flag  day  month  year 
4  2018-06-17   216.62  1000 0002     7   17      6  2018  
5  2018-06-18   161.61  1000 0002     6   18      6  2018   
8  2018-08-21   100.57  0000 0001     6   21      8  2018  
9  2018-08-22    50.57  0000 0001     5   22      8  2018
```

And `df_train =`

```
         date   income    account  flag  day  month  year
0  2018-04-13   470.57  1000 0002     8   13      4  2018  
1  2018-04-14   375.54  1000 0002     8   14      4  2018  
2  2018-05-15   375.54  1000 0002     8   15      5  2018  
3  2018-05-16   229.04  1000 0002     7   16      5  2018  
6  2018-04-19   131.87  0000 0001     6   19      4  2018  
7  2018-04-20   100.57  0000 0001     6   20      4  2018
```

So for example, for `df['account'] = 1000 0002` I can use months 4 and 5 to predict, and month 6 to validate. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do with `transform`

```
test=df[df.month==df.groupby('account').month.transform('max')].copy()
train=df.drop(test.index)
test
Out[643]: 
         date  income   account  flag  day  month  year
4  2018-06-17  216.62  10000002     7   17      6  2018
5  2018-06-18  161.61  10000002     6   18      6  2018
8  2018-08-21  100.57         1     6   21      8  2018
9  2018-08-22   50.57         1     5   22      8  2018
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution! I will try it in a minute and upvote if it works :) Thanks!